# How to use printf with to ouput a value from an Enum - Java

Tags: java, enums, printf

I'm trying to use the **printf** function to output a value of an **enum** but can't seem to find a way to get it done.

I know I've done it wrong, but a little help would be much appreciated.

Please see the code below to see my problem.

### CarType enum class

```
public enum CarType {
    Sport,
    Hatchback,
    Saloon,
    Super
}
```

### Garage class

```
public void printList() {
        for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
            System.out.println("Car Type: %s%n", CarType.valueOf());
        }
    }
```

### Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Garage g = new Garage();
    g.addVehicle(CarType.Super);
}
```

Comment: I don't know your vehicle class, but you might be able to write something like System.out.printf("Car Type: %s%n", v.carType.toString());

Comment: @Bruce Feldman: the manual `toString()` invocation is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString` method works for enum's.  Assuming that the `Vehicle` class has a method `CarType getCarType()`, try:

```
for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
    System.out.println("Car Type: %s%n", v.getCarType().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to output an **integral value** for the enumerator, you would have to provide each of your enumerators with an integral value. Java enumerators do not have default integral values like C's enumerators.

```
public enum CarType {
    Sport(0),
    Hatchback(1),
    Saloon(2),
    Super(3);

    private m_ordinal;
    CarType( int ordinal ) { 
        m_ordinal = ordinal;
    }

    public getOrdinalValue() { return m_ordinal; }
```

}

If you're asking how to output the **name of the enumerator**, you can do that with the name() method.

```
System.out.println( CarType.Sport.name() );
```

For example, with your code:

```
for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
    System.out.printf( "Car Type: %s%n",
       v.getCarType().name());
}
```

However, if you're looking for a **name suitable for display to a user**, it's better to use the toString() method, which you can modify to provide a display name.

```
for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
    System.out.printf("Car Type: %s%n", 
           v.getCarType().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple choices... all of them required the right implementation of the method **valueOf**

```
System.out.printf("Car Type: %s", CarType.valueOf("Super").name());
System.out.printf("Car Type: %s", CarType.valueOf("Super"));
System.out.printf("Car Type: %d", CarType.valueOf("Super").ordinal());
```